# How to bundle a Gnome applet with distutils?

Tags: python, applet, gnome, distutils

I'm trying to write a Gnome applet in Python. In fact, I've written the app and I'm stuck when it comes to packaging it.

I started by looking into [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/). The problem I ran into right away was that when specifying `py_modules`, an extension of `.py` is expected. However, Gnome applets are basically shell scripts. (That use the Python interpreter, of course.)

Here is what I tried... but it isn't working.

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='myapp',
    version='1.2',
    py_modules=['myapp'],
)
```

Also, the `myapp` file has to get put in `/usr/lib/myapp/`. As far as I know, `distutils` puts the files in with the other modules.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: #gnome `irc.freenode.net` may be a good source of help

Comment: @Tim McNamara: Official IRC #gnome channel is in gimpnet, not freenode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts should be installed with the `script` option to `distutils.core.setup()` as described in [`distutils` documentation](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts). On the other hand, `py_modules` is used to [list individual modules](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-individual-modules), and they must have `.py` extension as you described.

Also, if you want to add additional files, the [`data_files` option](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) lets you specify both source and destination of the files.

Answer summary: Read [whole `distutils` documentation](http://docs.python.org/distutils).